# Limit query string to a specific range using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm working on a website that allows you to show a certain number of products in a category at once based on a drop-down. Currently the highest the drop-down allows is 100 products shown. The URL appends always at the very end a query like "**?limit=100**" or "**?limit=50**" depending on how many you choose.

We noticed very large amounts of traffic with URLs ending in "**?limit=500**" or "**?limit=10000**" pulling huge amounts of products at once. It seems you can manually enter any number into the URL query and it will return as many as possible or at least as many are in that category; some categories have over 2000 products which of course is very resource intensive.

We've been researching most of the day on how to mitigate this and our best guess would be with .htaccess

We currently have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^?]*\?limit=[1,0]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

We want to only allow up to 100 results shown, no more. If someone/bot manually enters in the URL a greater value like 101 or 10000 it should automatically go back to 100, or simply remove the **?limit=** query from the end, so the default 25 products will automatically be shown.

With the above code in our .htaccess file, it does indeed block requests though it shows the following error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access (CATEGORY/SUBCATEGORY) on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Oddly enough it only shows this error if you query above "**limit=99**"- In other words limit=1 to limit=99 work; and display the correct number of products. 100 and above throw the 403 error - I can't seem to figure out how to effect only queries greater than 100 and have the RewriteRule work as mentioned above. I'm new to .htaccess and I apologize if this particular problem is answered elsewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know that I'd do this with .htaccess --  I would use server-side code on the product page .. If you were using say `PHP` -- It would be REALLY simple to throw 3 lines up top that say `if ($_POST['limit'] > 50){ header('Location: ?limit=50'); }` Which should redirect the person to the page with a limit of 50 --  And if you didn't want the redirect, you could simply say `$_POST['limit'] = 50;` and your page will treat it like they only asked for 50 even though the limit is set to 1000

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The site does use PHP, though we wouldn't know where to place such a code and if any modifications would be needed to your example to fit the site in particular. The owner of the site would have no issues with paid compensation for help solving this issue in any way.